# Issues with check free memory in centos server

Tags: linux, server

I have a VM centos server. i recive many complaint from users, the server run slowly (it is a java application)

I execute this command to check free memory

```
[root@server ~]# free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             11           3           6           0           1           7
Swap:             9           0           9
```

and we have much of free memory (7Gb available and 6Gb free)

i check the CPU Consomation : it is 0%

```
[root@server ~]# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                3
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 94
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 v5 @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               2999.999
BogoMIPS:              5999.99
Hypervisor vendor:     Microsoft
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-2
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms rtm xsaveopt
```

any idea ?

EDIT :

```
[root@server ~]# vmstat 1 5
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 6359520   2108 1381056    0    0    42    11   21  292  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 6359504   2108 1381060    0    0     0     0   35  801  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 6359504   2108 1381060    0    0     0     0   31  762  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 6359504   2108 1381060    0    0     0     0   32  763  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0      0 6359504   2108 1381060    0    0     0    12   28  761  0  0 100  0  0
```

Comment: You are complaining about the speed of an application, which is not related to the amount of free memory of the machine, the application is running on.

Comment: @Dominique sorry, but what do you mean with "You are complaining about the speed of an application, which is not related to the amount of free memory of the machine, the application is running on. " ?

my server is not able to runnig my application ?

Comment: please add output of `vmstat 1 5` to the question

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me there are no problems with CPU and memory, try to check top output(top is the command), then press "1" to see load by CPU, maybe you will see some problems(for example hight io usage)